# how to encrypt post parameters

Tags: api, post, encryption

I'm trying to get an api response of a site.
This site says `encrypted POST parameters with HMAC-SHA512 alghoritm using your secret API key` but I have not the slightest clue how to do that. Each method I tried resulted in the same `error: "Missing Key or Signature.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$key = 'API_KEY';
$secret = 'SECRET_KEY';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://bitgrail.com/api/v1/balances");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $key);

$ch = hash_hmac('sha512',$ch,$secret);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($output);
```

Comment: Ask the website to provide sensible documentation.

Comment: Many people have complaint about it on reddit, as far as I've seen. I've never seen a poorly written documentation like this in a while. If you're curious this is the documentation: https://bitgrail.com/api-documentation

Comment: If that's all the detail that's available then it will be almost impossible to get anything working.

Answer (score 0):

From the api docs:

> All private calls have to be composed by HTTP POST call, containing following 2 headers:
>   KEY - Public API key
>   SIGNATURE - encrypted POST parameters with HMAC-SHA512 alghoritm using your secret API key
>   Private calls, overmore, need the additional POST parameter, the nonce
>   nonce - Integer number, always greater then nonce of previous call.

So you have to create two headers, KEY (your key) and SIGNATURE (an HMAC  hash of the post data with your secret as key).

> Balances
>   To get balances of all coins present on BitGrail you don't need parameters, except the authentication ones.

I assume that means you don't have to submit any post data, except from the nonce.

Code:

```
$key = 'API_KEY';
$secret = 'SECRET_KEY';
$url = "https://bitgrail.com/api/v1/balances";
$data = http_build_query(array("nonce" => time()));
$sig = hash_hmac('sha512', $data, $secret);
$headers = array("KEY: $key", "SIGNATURE: $sig");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```